When we say brachos, why are there 2 pronouns for Hashem?
When we say shehakol for example, we say "ברוך אתה ה" and "שהכל נהיה בדברו"
Why refer to Him in the second person, and for the rest of the bracha in the 3rd? Shouldn't it be "בדברך" instead of בדברו?
I've noticed this is the case in pretty much every other bracha.
Does anyone have an official answer?

I have always heard it in my mind as "Blessed are You..., [for You are the One from Whom] everything comes from His word" but I would love to see an official answer for this. Good question imo +1

@RabbiKaii id like to think the reason that we dont use second person pronouns in the latter part of the bracha is because it might be disrespectful to only mention one thing hashem has done for us, when hes done so much! But when we speak about him in the 3rd person we arent afraid of underappreciating him chas veshalom

This isn't true of brachot that continue asher kidishanu.

@rosends yes it is. "במצוותו" not "במצוותך"

@JoelK woah i had no idea. I looked for a similar question, seems like you found it. Should i delete mine?

@ShmuelT No, don’t delete it. Duplicates are good. Someone in the future might search and find this question, which will then point him to the other one.
